# Html encoding with foreign language character

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter, localization

I am working on a project supporting multi-language. I am using PHP-Codeigniter and MySQL.

My DB collation is utf8-unicode-ci.

My html page is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

I am getting �� in some part of page.Following is some part of page.

```
<div id="navbar" class="jmenu collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav-kp"><li class="dropdown"><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/251">
                                बच्चे जोन
                                                        </a><ul><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/271">
                                ज्ञान
                                                        </a></li><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/261">
                                कार्य
                                                        </a></li></ul></li><li class="dropdown"><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/211">
                                किशोर
                                                        </a><ul><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/221">
                                फ़ैशन
                                                        </a></li><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/231">
                                खाना पकाना
                                                        </a></li><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/291">
                                मज़ा
                                                        </a></li></ul></li><li class="dropdown"><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/151">
                                पत्ते
                                                        </a><ul><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/161">
                                पोकर
                                                        </a></li><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/181">
                                ब्लैक जैक
                                                        </a></li></ul></li><li class="dropdown"><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/91">
                                रणनीति
                                                        </a><ul><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/101">
                                पहेली
                                                        </a></li><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/241">
                                प्रश्नोत्तरी
                                                        </a></li></ul></li><li class="dropdown"><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/39">
                                खेल
                                                        </a><ul><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/40">
                                टेनिस
                                                        </a></li><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/42">
                                बॅस्केटबॉल
                                                        </a></li><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/46">
                                पूल
                                                        </a></li><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/47">
                                शीतकालीन खेल
                                                        </a></li><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/48">
                                मोटो खेल
                                                        </a></li><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/49">
                                ग्रीष्मकालीन खेल
                                                        </a></li><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/50">
                                फ़ुटबॉल
                                                        </a></li><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/111">
                                गोल्फ़
                                                        </a></li><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/121">
                                रग्बी
                                                        </a></li><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/131">
                                क्रिकेट
                                                        </a></li><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/191">
                                बेसबॉल
                                                        </a></li></ul></li><li class="dropdown"><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/37">
                                कार्य
                                                        </a><ul><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/38">
                                लड़ाई
                                                        </a></li><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/41">
                                रणनीति
                                                        </a></li><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/44">
                                दौड़
                                                        </a></li><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/45">
                                फ्लाइंग
                                                        </a></li><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/141">
                                नृत्य
                                                        </a></li><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/Games/281">
                                साहसिक कार्य
                                                        </a></li></ul></li></ul>                  </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
                </div>
.
.
.
                <div id="game-39" class="owl-carousel">
                                            <div class="item post2">
                        <a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/24" style="min-height:60px;">
                            <img class="lazyOwl" data-src="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/content/24/8ballpoolmultiplayerv7[1].jpg" alt="8 गेंद ��..."/>8 गेंद ��...                         </a>
                    </div>
                                            <div class="item post2">
                        <a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/21" style="min-height:60px;">
                            <img class="lazyOwl" data-src="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/content/21/flashtennis[1].jpg" alt="फ्लैश �..."/>फ्लैश �...                            </a>
                    </div>
                                            <div class="item post2">
                        <a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/23" style="min-height:60px;">
                            <img class="lazyOwl" data-src="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/content/23/shootinhoops[1].jpg" alt="शुतीन �..."/>शुतीन �...                           </a>
                    </div>
                                            <div class="item post2">
                        <a href="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/apps/241" style="min-height:60px;">
                            <img class="lazyOwl" data-src="http://localhost/konnectplay/ITN-KonnectPlay/PLAY/content/241/rugbychallenge[1].jpg" alt="रग्बी �..."/>रग्बी �...                            </a>
                    </div>
```

This is not happening in whole page it is happening in certain part of page.

Comment: do you have any sample data?

Comment: is your data `CHARACTER SET ` is `utf8` ?

Comment: i have just edited please check.
@Noman: how i know my data character set. It's coming in page correctly but not in other.

Comment: You have to check the encoding of the files in question, those which are the php source(s) of the respective pages or parts thereof.

Answer (score 0):

Run below query in database using `phpmyadmin` / `SQLYog`. 
Change `DBNAME` in query also for `tablename` .

```
ALTER DATABASE DBNAME CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

you can also change database configuration in `database.php`

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_unicode_ci';
```

> If `utf8_unicode_ci` does not seems to work you may also use `utf8_general_ci`

**Update 1:**

change meta remove spaces from `content` attribute

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

OR use php header for content type.

```
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
```

Comment: i am fetching in right format from database, means getting correct data if i use var_dump($data) but in html page it shows error

Comment: @AmmarHayderKhan see update 1, it seems you page does not recognise the content type.

Answer (score 0):

Use Codeigniter predefined functions. I'm using same and no harms at all.

```
echo meta('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'equiv');
```

Sometime this shouldn't works to you. Just a tip

[Codeigniter `meta()` Function](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/html_helper.html?highlight=meta#meta)

Comment: if answer is helpful accept it. So its help to new users without duplicate. Thank You